# How to check gravity scale on a Rigibody2D in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have a script called playerMovement and with it I am adding different forces to make a player move. I have no problem adding forces on the x axis however, when the user presses space I want to flip the gravity.

I am doing this by doing `rb.gravityScale = -1;` which works fine however I want to check if the gravity is positive or negative so I can adjust from there.

This is where I run into a problem when I put

```
if(Input.GetKey("space")){
    if(rb.gravityScale = 1){
        rb.gravityScale = -1;
    }
    else {
        rb.gravityScale = 1;
    }
}
```

I get an error saying

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'bool'

Comment: This is in C# right?

Comment: Yes it is @LeoGaunt

Comment: correct if condition with if(rb.gravityScale == 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. You need to use == instead of = when you check equality.
= stands for value assignment.

```
if(Input.GetKey("space")){
    if(rb.gravityScale == 1){
        rb.gravityScale = -1;
    }
    else {
        rb.gravityScale = 1;
    }
}
```